# Style for TabItem's content

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have `TabControl` which is used as a main element of my app:
[image]

Every tab content would have a title (duplicate to the menu name), separater and content. My XAML code which must correspond to this view should be like this:

```
<TabControl Style="{StaticResource MyCustomStyle}">
    <TabItem Header="Menu 1">
        <TabItem.Content>
            ...
        </TabItem.Content>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Menu 2">
        <TabItem.Content>
            <TextBlock>Content</TextBlock>
        </TabItem.Content>
    </TabItem>
    ...
</TabControl>
```

To avoid duplicating parts of the code, I decided to setup view in custom style.
`MyCustomStyle` for this:

```
<Style x:Key="MyCustomStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="120"/>
            <Setter Property="Content">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <StackPanel Margin="10">
                        <Label FontSize="20" Content="..."/>
                        <Separator/>
                        <ContentPresenter ContentSource="..."/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
    <Setter Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Left"/>
</Style>
```

The only problem occurs with the modification of content. Label don't want to bind value to the `TabItem`'s header. The same story for `ContentPresenter`

I tried to use `RelativeSource` for this, but this is not working:

```
<Label FontSize="20" Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}}, Path=Header}"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're very close -- you just want to give it a `ContentTemplate` instead of setting the `Content` in the style:

```
<Style x:Key="MyCustomStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="120"/>
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Margin="10">
                            <Label FontSize="20" Content="..."/>
                            <Separator/>
                            <ContentControl 
                                Content="{Binding}"
                                />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
    <Setter Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Left"/>
</Style>
```

Now, for the Label content. You can't get that via `RelativeSource AncestorType` because `TabItem` isn't in the visual tree: If you write a `VisualTreeHelper.GetParent()` loop, you find that the parent chain hits a bunch of random stuff like Grids and whatnot, then suddenly it's on `TabControl`.

So what we do instead, is we write a multi-value converter. We give it the `DataContext` for the `DataTemplate` -- that's the `Content` for the `TabItem` being ContentTemplated -- and the `TabControl`. Then we look through the `TabControl`'s `Items` to find the `TabItem` that has the same `Content`.

I tried this as a regular valueconverter, just passing in `{RelativeSource Self}` from the `Label`, walking the visual tree inside the converter to find the `TabControl`, and using the `Label`'s `DataContext` inside the converter to identify the `TabItem` I wanted. That didn't work because of (I think) virtualization: The `DataTemplate` is instantiated once and those controls are reused. Since the value of `{RelativeSource Self}` is the same each time, and I didn't tell the `Binding` anything about `DataContext`, the value converter was only invoked for the first `TabItem` that was ever selected. The multi-value converter fixes that problem by explicitly binding to `.`, the `DataContext`.

This breaks if you use `ItemsSource` to populate the `TabControl`. In fact, it breaks if you populate the `TabControl` with anything but `TabItems` just like you did. But then, you couldn't be setting their `Header` properties otherwise, and if you were using `ItemsSource`, you'd have all kinds of good things to bind to and you wouldn't be contemplating nutty expedients like this one.

TabItemHeaderConverter.cs

```
public class TabItemHeaderConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    //  This is pretty awful, but nobody promised life would be perfect. 
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var tc = values[0] as TabControl;
        var tabItemContent = values[1];

        var tabItem = tc.Items.Cast<TabItem>().FirstOrDefault(ti => ti.Content == tabItemContent);

        if (null != tabItem)
        {
            return tabItem.Header;
        }

        return "Unknown";
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And the new XAML:

```
<Style x:Key="MyCustomStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <local:TabItemHeaderConverter x:Key="TabItemHeaderConverter" />

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="120"/>
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Margin="10">
                            <Label 
                                FontSize="20" 
                                >
                                <Label.Content>
                                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource TabItemHeaderConverter}">
                                        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=TabControl}" />
                                        <Binding Path="." />
                                    </MultiBinding>
                                </Label.Content>
                            </Label>
                            <Separator />
                            <ContentControl 
                                Content="{Binding}"
                            />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
    <Setter Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Left"/>
</Style>
```

Comment: `<ContentPresenter/>` cause a StackOverflowException. If remove it, then application can be launched. But label is still not working.

Comment: @Serbin Whoops, my mistake -- I should have changed that. That needs to be `<ContentControl Content="{Binding}" />`.

Comment: Any ideas for Label content?

Comment: That's tough, because TabItem isn't in the visual tree. If you follow VisualTreeHelper.GetParent() upward from any control in that DataTemplate, you hit the TabControl itself without hitting a TabItem.

Comment: @Serbin Nevertheless, I got it working. See answer update.

Comment: @Serbin Actually, I hadn't got it working -- but it's working now.